# Loop over array and then loop backwards. [C]

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to make a program looping over array and then looping backwards. How can I make it better with less code in C? Array has 8 elements!

```
while (1) {
    if (i == 0) {
        direction = 0; // RIGHT DIRECTION
    }
    if (i == 7) {
        direction = 1; // LEFT DIRECTION
    }
    PORTD = array[i]; // NEEDED ARRAY ELEMENT

    if (direction == 0) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make direction `1` or `-1`. Then add it to `i`. But you need stop condition too.

Comment: Stop condition can be >= 0

Comment: @LuQ232 Without a context the provided code snippet does not make a sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I would guess it is making an LED to run left and right on 8-LED array. Not clear what `array` is for though

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah. You're right. In array im holding number of LED which will be turned on. like 
```int array [] = 
{0b00000001,0b00000010,0b00000100,0b00001000,0b00010000,0b00100000,0b01000000,0b10000000};```

Comment: Next time i'll give more informations. Sorry guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code by making `direction` the increment for the next index, `1` or `-1`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
int i = 0, direction = 1;
for (i = 0;; i += direction) {
    if (i == 0) {
        direction = 1; // RIGHT DIRECTION
    } else
    if (i == 7) {
        direction = -1; // LEFT DIRECTION
    }
    PORTD = array[i]; // NEEDED ARRAY ELEMENT
}
```

Comment: `if ( i == 0 || i == 7 ) { direction *= -1; }` would be even less typing, as long as the initial sign of direction is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you need to reverse the sign of the increment variable, and you then need to use a proper condition to terminate the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
  int i = 0, direction = 1;
  int PORTD, array[8] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17};

  for (i = 0 ; i >= 0 ; i += direction)
    {
    PORTD = array[i];

    printf("i=%d array[%d]=%d\n", i, i, array[i]);

    if(i == (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))-1 )
      direction = -1;
    }
  }
```